# Is a keyed PRF a MAC?

Tags: mac, pseudo-random-function

I remember I read that a MAC can be considered as a PRF.

Can a variable-length input keyed-PRF be considered as a MAC?

Comment: I'd note that the first statement is incorrect: a secure MAC is not necessarily a secure PRF. Consider any secure MAC and add a single zero bit in the end. The result is clearly not random, but equally secure as a MAC.

Answer (score 3):

Usually. $\:$ A variable-length input keyed-PRF is a [PRF's output length]-bit MAC.

In particular, a variable-length input keyed-PRF *with long output* is automatically a MAC.

Comment: I would add that we are talking about secure PRFs and secure MACs.