# Is a PRF applied to a secure MAC also a secure MAC?

Tags: provable-security, mac, pseudo-random-function

Suppose I apply a PRF to a secure MAC.  Do I still have a secure MAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

A secure PRF [is a secure MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17974/is-a-keyed-prf-a-mac). A secure MAC of a secure MAC is a secure MAC. Therefore, applying a PRF to a MAC still gives you a MAC.

Depending on the length of the inner MAC and the PRF you may lose security bits, but if they are long enough it works.

Comment: One needs some condition on the PRF's input and output size; otherwise, a PRF applied to a secure MAC could well be a much less secure MAC than the original MAC is. Even if the PRF's input and output are the MAC's output size, odds of forgery by reusing a former MAC value are slightly better for the resulting MAC than they are for the original MAC.

Comment: @fgrieu, yes, the linked question mentioned length, but I added it explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you're asking if PRF(MAC) can be used as MAC (message authentication code)? Depends on the PRF. MAC is de-factor PRF too with several properties in mind (collision resistance, pre-image resistance, avalanche effect, non-linearity...).

Until your PRF keeps these properties, you should be ok. The basic idea is you should not weak the strength (length) of the MAC.